# In SQL Server 2019 / SSRS, are the SQL database engine and report server names supposed to be different?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have been trying to install & configure SQL Server 2019 & SSRS developer editions for 5 days (I have had several versions of SQL Server and SSRS on my computer in the past few years and have attempted to uninstall every thing I could).

I have tried using the same name (the SQL database engine) in the report server configuration manager for database, but the only option that shows up for SSRS in the SSMS object explorer is "SSRS".  Also, my `ReportServer` and `ReportServerTemp` databases show under the SQL database engine which I am not sure is correct.

My `rsreportserver.config` file has "SSRS" in it and is dated the day I recently installed SSRS. This file also has a database name in code that I can't read. I am currently blocked by a different issue but I wanted to make sure I was starting to go in the right direction.

Thanks, Ginger

Answer (score 0):

You can run both the database engine and SSRS undser the same name on the same server. E.g. If your database server is called `myServer` and your `ReportServer` database is located on this server then, by default, the SSRS web portal would be located at `http://myServer/Reports` and the reports folder would be accessible at `http://myServer/Reportserver`, you should be able to confirm this from the Reporting Services Configuration manager